# Programmatically delete field collection items

Tags: 8, entities

Is there any way to delete field collection items programmatically in Drupal 8?

I have created a field collection item and attached it to the user entity in the following method.

```
$user_id = \Drupal::currentUser()->getAccount()->id();
$user = User::load($user_id);

$fc = FieldCollectionItem::create(array(
  "field_name" => "field_hobbies",
));

$fc->set('field_name', 'Watch TV');
$fc->setHostEntity($user);
```

It works fine and the field collection item got created successfully. Now I want to delete this field collection item. That means, I want to delete the hobby from the user. Is there any way for doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Copied from (and then tested):

https://www.drupal.org/node/2757827#comment-11398243

```
$user = User::load($user_id);
$storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('field_collection_item');
$fc_items = [];

foreach ($user->get('field_hobbies') as $item) {
    $fc_items[] = $item->value;
}

if (!empty($fc_items)) {
    $items = $storage->loadMultiple($fc_items);
    $storage->delete(items);
    $user->set('field_hobbies', array());
}

$user->save();
```